# How to apply for a visa for a stateless person to come to Canada from the Netherlands

Tags: visas, canada, netherlands, stateless-persons

My girlfriend and her daughter are living in the Netherlands.

Her daughter has a Dutch passport but she does not.

Is there anyway that she can apply for a visa to come to Canada for a visit?

And can she apply for alien’s passport for stateless person?

Comment: If she has a Cambodian passport as you suggest in a comment below, then she is not stateless.

Comment: Is the daughter a minor?

Comment: Yes, her daughter is 11 years old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

She can [apply for a visa for Canada](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/apply-visitor-visa/paper-outside.html), but she will need to obtain the alien's passport first, because this is the travel document in which the visa will be placed. Note that Canada will require that she file a paper application, and [will not accept an online application](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/apply-visitor-visa.html) from anyone using an alien's passport from the Netherlands.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, she can apply for a visa to visit Canada. She will need some kind of travel document. From [Find out if you need a visa](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp):

[image]

Comment: She does have a cambodian passport. Does it count? Or she has to apply for alien’s passport? Thanks for all your help guys. I’m very appreciated.

Comment: An alien’s passport will only be issued in cases where a national passport cannot/will not be issued. Does the Cambodian passport contain a valid Dutch residence permit. If yes, that must be used.